# I have a custom edittext I made with XML only that in the KITKAT version it gets with the black background

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat

This is the custom edittext XML code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <corners android:radius="90dp"/>
    <padding android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

edittext xml code

```
 <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtRegistration"
      style="@style/editText_style"
      android:textColor="@color/colorText"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

follows the style being used in edittext

```
<style name="editText_style">
       <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_text_login</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:ems">10</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#100</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#6F7A8B</item>
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Above the Android Lollipop it stays as it has to be, like this:[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElH6t.jpg)

In android kitkat it gets all bugged the edittext bakground turns black:[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1Y7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@null"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="90dp"/>
    <padding android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

use this code for the drawable background, this may works.

Comment: if this answer help you please mark it as correct answer